# Where was the castle in Heaven Sent?

Tags: doctor-who, real-location

In *Doctor Who* Series 9 Episode 11, *Heaven Sent*, the Doctor spends almost the entire episode in a castle. Some of the shots of this castle could be CGI, but **was any of it filmed in a real castle, and if so which real castle and where?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4701542/locations) lists one filming location

> Black Hangar Studios, Hampshire, England, UK

However, the [Heaven Sent Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven_Sent_%28Doctor_Who%29) adds

> Filming for the Castle interior scenes took place in Cardiff Castle and Caerphilly Castle, in addition to constructed sets

And further links to [Rachel Talalay's](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4701542/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3)<sup>**1**</sup> tumblr entry [Notes on Heaven Sent](http://racheltalalay.tumblr.com/post/135339295759/notes-on-heaven-sent-part-1) which includes the following information

> We location-scouted castles: Caerphilly, Cardiff, St Donat’s (William Randolph Hearst’s house/castle in Wales, now a  school), Castle Coch, Raglands, and Chepstow. Each had elements that could work, but we used only the first two — St Donat’s was a wish-list addition, but was ultimately difficult to shoot for the complicated scenes we were placing there.

<sup>**1**<sub>The director of the episode!</sub></sup>

Comment: @Randal'Thor There are some nice photos of the space available at [Black Hangar Studios](http://www.blackhangarstudios.com/) too.

Comment: She almost certainly means Raglan Castle, not "Raglands".